# Convert 3 columns dataframe to a matrix - Change the names of similar column

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a 3 columns data frame, which I try to convert it to a matrix.

```
Name    Act   value
Alex    C1     100
John    C2     100
Matt    C3     252
Alex    C1     456
Alex    C5     234
John    C5     456
Tina    C2     897
Matt    C2     652
Jorge   C1     344
Alex    C1     34
Matt    C3     231
```

I want to have something like:

```
       C1   C1.1  C1.2   C2   C3  C3.1   C4   C5
Alex   100   456   34                        234
John                     100                 456
Matt                     652  252  231  
Tina                     897
Jorge  344
```

I mean, since I have similar names that made the same act having different/same score, I want to instead of summing the values and put them in a cell of a matrix, generate a separate column for that act (while having a number at the end of the name).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Name) %>%
 mutate(Act = make.unique(Act)) %>%
 spread(Act, value)

  Name     C1  C1.1  C1.2    C2    C3  C3.1    C5
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Alex    100   456    34    NA    NA    NA   234
2 John     NA    NA    NA   100    NA    NA   456
3 Jorge   344    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 Matt     NA    NA    NA   652   252   231    NA
5 Tina     NA    NA    NA   897    NA    NA    NA
```